# SCCM SP2 - Cannot Find amtopmgr.log File

Tags: sccm

I've installed SCCM SP2 -> primary site, management point.
I imported to it a vPro computer, but it's AMT status is "Unknown" instead of "Not Provisioned". I wanted to check the reason, but I can't find the file amtopmgr.log (it should be there).

Why this file wasn't created? How can I solve it?
(I tried to create this file manually - didn't help...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The silly answer is that I didn't install yet OOB management role...